# Squid working on linux machine but not on vmware

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a friend that is getting started to learn squid, so I am trying to give him a very basic squid.conf file that blocks only 3 websites. I got it running on my local machine which runs Ubuntu. I sent him the file, but his squid doesn't start anymore. Note that he's running Ubuntu on a vmware.

When he starts the service, it tells him that service started but ps -ef|grep squid3 gives nothing back.

here's the squid.conf without the comments:

```
acl all src all
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24
acl localnet src 192.168.2.0/24
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
acl websites_to_block dstdomain .youtube.com .mashable.com .linkedin.com
http_access deny websites_to_block
http_access allow localnet 
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
visible_hostname minus
```

Answer (score 0):

You should examine /var/log/squid3/cache.log - this log file should contain useful information on why squid is failing.
Also make sure your friend is running the same squid version. Some configuration parameters changed in recent squid releases, such as the localhost and to_localhost are predefined, as well as the manager ACL. There are useful release notes on this on the squid wiki.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for answering this question.  It would be useful if you could add a link to the squid wiki in your answer.